# How to go to next layout(not activity) when pressed button?

Tags: android, layout, android-layout

I want to create the instruction, so when user press the next button I want to set to the 
next layout page. I tried `setContentView(R.layout.aboutus);` but it looks like to set the new
layout to particular page.

**Layout:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#dddddd">
        <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:background = "@drawable/aboutus"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**code :**

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long lg) {
            switch (position) {

            case 4:
                setContentView(R.layout.aboutus);
            }

        }
```

So, I want to know how to go to next layout without new activity and can be back to previous page. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please descibe your page or view it's code?

Comment: I edited my question, please see above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a `ViewFlipper`.

Get a reference to the ViewFlipper:

```
ViewFlipper myViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.my_viewFlipper);
```

You then inflate each page as a view:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.your_layout_id, null);
```

And then add it to the ViewFlipper:

```
myViewFlipper.addView( view );
```

Then when the user hits the button for next page you call this method:

```
myViewFlipper.showNext();
```

Or if you want the previous page:

```
myViewFlipper.showPrevious();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a ViewSwitcher or ViewFlipper.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to place the same page in your layout and set all it's component to have `Visibility.GONE` set, and when you press the button, to set all your visible widgets to GONE and others to Visible. Or you can try a dynamically inflate procedure ( to inflate your views ) since you can use separate layout to inflate views. 
Check this for more information about inflate 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Answer (score 0):

May be you could do this:

If you have two different layouts and one wanna each one at one time.

First get the id's of each layout by `findviewbyid` method.

then use

```
    firstlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE).
     secondlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

for showing first layout.

When you press button, in its click listener make

```
     firstlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE).
     secondlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

it works but the layouts should be seperate.

Hope it helps.